# Double-sided document with CV class

Tags: margins, double-sided

I am using the CV class defined like this:

```
%% Copyright (c) 2003-2009 Fr????ic Meynadier  
%% Original : Eric-Olivier Le Bigot
%% Modifs : Fr????ic Meynadier (Frederic.Meynadier@obspm.fr)
%% Modifs : Dominique Quatravaux (dom@idealx.com) - conversion en
%%     classe de document.
%% 03/01/03
%% Modifs : application d'un patch de Jonas Kahn, 2007-12-19
%% Modifs : anonymisation de l'exemple en commentaire, 2009-02-25

%% Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a
%% copy of this software and associated documentation files (the
%% "Software"), to deal in the Software without restriction, including
%% without limitation the rights to use, copy, modify, merge, publish,
%% distribute, sublicense, and/or sell copies of the Software, and to
%% permit persons to whom the Software is furnished to do so, subject to
%% the following conditions:

%% The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in
%% all copies or substantial portions of the Software.

%% THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS
%% OR IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF
%% MERCHANTABILITY, FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT.
%% IN NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY
%% CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT,
%% TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE
%% SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.



\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{cv}
  [2002/01/03 v0.1 Curriculum Vitae package]

\LoadClass[11pt]{article}
\RequirePackage{ifthen}
\RequirePackage{array}

   %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
   % Mise en page par d??aut %
   %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\setlength{\textwidth}{160mm}    %% Largeur de la zone texte
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0mm}  %% Texte centr??sur la page

\pagestyle{empty} % pour ne pas indiquer de num??o de page...

% On d??init les pieds de page comme des \stretch de force 1,
% soit 4 plus fort que celui qui est en bas du chapeau
% (Cf. ci-dessous). De cette fa??n, un CV qui ne remplit pas toute la
% page a un bel espacement.
\makeatletter
\def\@textbottom{\vspace*{\stretch{1}}}
\makeatother


   %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
   %      Param??res r??lables          %
   %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% L'utilisateur peut les red??inir ceux-ci ?\renewcommand? si besoin :

\newcommand{\espaceInterRubrique}{\medskip\vspace{\stretch{0.1}}}

% L'utilisateur peut les red??inir ceux-ci ?\setlength? si besoin :

\newlength{\rubriquetableauparindent} % indentation au d??ut d'une
% ligne de droite dans un ?rubriquetableau?. Cette longueur peut
% ??re n??ative, auquel cas l'alignement dans le tableau se fait
% compte tenu du retrait de la premi??e ligne : celle-ci ne ?bavera?
% pas sur l'espace r??erv??pour la colonne de gauche, au lieu de cela,
% l'ensemble de la colonne de droite est d??al??de l'espace correspondant.

\setlength{\rubriquetableauparindent}{0pt}


   %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
   %     Macros pratiques       %
   %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\def\er{$^{\hbox{er}}$}
\def\ere{$^{\hbox{??e}}$}
\def\eme{$^{\hbox{??e}}$}

   %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
   % L'environnement "rubrique" %
   %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% Usage : \begin{rubrique}[Indentation]{Titre} [...] \end{rubrique}
% On met le texte qu'on veut ??l'int??ieur.

\newenvironment{rubrique}[1]   % "rubrique" prend un seul argument, le titre
{\espaceInterRubrique\relax%
\noindent\textbf{\large #1}\par%
\noindent\rule[0.5ex]{\textwidth}{0.1mm}\par}{}

   %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
   % L'environnement "rubriquetableau" %
   %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% Il sert ??rendre les tableaux, avec typiquement des dates ??gauche
% et des activit?? ??droite. Il s'utilise comme ?rubrique?
% ci-dessus, sauf qu'il admet un argument optionnel qui est la largeur
% de la colonne de gauche, et que l'int??ieur doit ??re un tableau
% LaTeX avec les ?&? et les ?\\? qui vont bien.
% Par exemple :
%
% \begin{rubriquetableau}[3.5cm]{pipotage}
% 1999--2000    & ligne 1\\
%       & ligne 2\\
% 1998--1999    & ligne 1\\
% [etc...]
% \end{rubriquetableau}
%
% Lorsqu'on omet le param??re entre crochets, cela a pour effet
% de donner la dimension \linewidth ??la premi??e colonne (mais la
% structure reste celle d'un tableau ??deux colonnes, donc ne pas oublier 
% d'??rire '\\' pour les retours ??la ligne).

\makeatletter

\newlength{\@cvlenB}\newlength{\@cvlenC}

\newenvironment{rubriquetableau}[2][\linewidth]%% "rubriquetableau" 
%                       % prend deux arguments
{\bgroup\rubrique{#2}%     % le second argument : titre
\setlength{\@cvlenB}{#1}%  % Le premier argument :indentation
\setlength{\@cvlenC}{\linewidth}%          % Calculs...
\ifthenelse{\lengthtest{\rubriquetableauparindent<0pt}}
   {\addtolength{\@cvlenC}{\rubriquetableauparindent}}
   {}
\addtolength{\@cvlenC}{-\@cvlenB}
\addtolength{\@cvlenC}{-41pt}
\begin{tabular}[t]{p{\@cvlenB}!{
   \ifthenelse{\lengthtest{\rubriquetableauparindent<0pt}}
          {\hspace*{-\rubriquetableauparindent}}
          {}
    }>{\setlength{\parindent}{\rubriquetableauparindent}}p{\@cvlenC}}}
{\end{tabular}\egroup}

\makeatother

   %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
   %    Le chapeau du CV        %
   %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\newenvironment{adresse}{
\begin{minipage}{5cm}
}
{
\end{minipage}\hfill}

\newenvironment{etatcivil}{
\begin{minipage}{10cm}

}
{
\end{minipage}}

\newenvironment{chapeau}{
\def\ligne{\rule[2pt]{24pt}{1pt}}
\noindent\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}\hspace{0cm}
}
{\end{minipage}\vspace{\stretch{0}}}
```

I would like to include it in a book class, and so I would like to have the same margins (double-sided). I set the length of my odd and even margins and add twoside when defining my documentclass. Minimal example:

```
\documentclass[twoside, a4paper, 11pt]{cv}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fourier}
\setlength{\textwidth}{146.8mm} 
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{11.6mm} 
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{0.8mm} 
\setlength{\topmargin}{-2.2mm} 
\setlength{\textheight}{221.9mm} 
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\lieu}[1]{{#1}\ }
\newcommand{\activite}[1]{\textbf{#1}\ }
\newcommand{\comment}[1]{\textsl{#1}\ }

\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\def\@maketitle{%
  \newpage
  \begin{center}%
  \let \footnote \thanks
    {\LARGE \@title \par}%
    \vskip 1.5em%
    {\large
      \lineskip .5em%
      \begin{tabular}[t]{c}%
        \@author
      \end{tabular}\par}%
    \vskip 1em%
    {\large \@date}%
  \end{center}%
  \par
  \vskip 1.5em}
\makeatother

\title{Curriculum Vitae}
\date{}

    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    % HEADER %
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{chapeau}
\begin{adresse}
    Name
\end{adresse}
\begin{etatcivil}
    other stuff
\end{etatcivil}
\vspace{0.6cm}

\end{chapeau}

    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    % CONTENT %
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{rubriquetableau}[3cm]{Education}

2011--2015  & \activite{A job}
    \lieu{In a cool place}

\end{rubriquetableau}

\begin{rubrique}{Experience}

Some text

\lipsum[1-2]

\lipsum[1-2]

\end{rubrique}

\begin{rubrique}{Skills}

More text

\lipsum[1-2]

\lipsum[1-2]

\end{rubrique}

\end{document}
```

It does not work. All margins are similar. What is wrong with my approach?

Comment: You would be better to use something like `geometry` than setting the page dimensions manually. This seems an odd class. Why does it use `\makeatletter`? It should pass options on to `article.cls` when it loads it rather than just throwing them away. It fails, basically, to do the elementary things which any class file should do.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is the following:

- Change `\LoadClass[11pt]{article}` to `\LoadClass[twoside, 11pt]{article}` in the cls file
- Remove the original `\setlength` from the cls file:
  `\setlength{\textwidth}{160mm}`
  `\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0mm}`
  and replace them by the `\setlength` from the tex file:
  `\setlength{\textwidth}{146.8mm}`
  `\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{11.6mm}`
  `\setlength{\evensidemargin}{0.8mm}`
  `\setlength{\topmargin}{-2.2mm}` 
  `\setlength{\textheight}{221.9mm}`
  `\setlength{\headheight}{14pt})`

By defining the double-sided format directy in the cls file, it works.